# await WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync waits forever but accessing Result property works

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task-parallel-library

The following piece of code works fine (prints the markup on the console):

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
var task1 = wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://www.google.com.au");
Console.WriteLine(task1.Result); // works
```

But when I await the task it just awaits forever and the task's state is WaitingForActivation:

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
var task1 = wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://www.google.com.au");
Console.WriteLine(await task1);
Console.WriteLine("done!"); // this never gets printed
```

What am I missing?

EDIT: full code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoIt(); 
}

static async void DoIt()
{
    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    var task1 = wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://www.google.com.au");
    Console.WriteLine(await task1);
    Console.WriteLine("done!"); // this never gets printed
}
```

Comment: Show how you use the piece of code...

Comment: @i3arnon I've updated the question. Please have a look.

Comment: The bug is using `async void` and never actually waiting for `DoIt` to finish - your console application terminates before DoIt has a chance to finish execution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I missing?

Currently, the way you're invoking your code, I see no way as to how the task is `WaitingForActivation`. As soon as `DoIt` hits the first `await`, it yields control back to the caller, which is your `Main` method, which should terminate and close your console.

Using `Task.Result` works because it synchronously blocks on the async method, hence it waits for it to complete and you see the result printed to the console.

What you actually need to do is make `DoIt` `async Task` instead of `async void`, and use `Task.Wait` there to synchronously block so `Main` won't terminate:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DoItAsync().Wait(); 
}

static async Task DoItAsync()
{
    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    var task1 = wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://www.google.com.au");
    Console.WriteLine(await task1);
    Console.WriteLine("done!"); // this never gets printed
}
```

Note using `Task.Result` and `Task.Wait` is only to make the console not terminate. In any other environment (UI based or ASP.NET), you shouldn't ever block on async code and should always `await` on async methods.

Comment: Thanks! Spot on explanation. But actually adding a simple Console.ReadLine() in main did the trick.

Comment: @Abhinav Yes, because that blocks on `Main` as well :). But, the recommended practice is to always return a `Task` or `Task<T>` from async methods, which I think is best to follow even if you use a simply console application, thus making `Console.ReadLine` redundant.

Answer (score 3):

You are not `await`-ing or `Wait()`-ing your `DoIt()` method which is `async`. As `Main()` can't be made `async`, your only option is to synchronously wait for the task to complete.

Also, it is not possible to `await` or `Wait()` async method which returns `void` so we have to make it to return `Task` (or `Task<T>`, if method has to return some value). Callers of the async method which returns `void` cannot know when it returns and also whether it throws any exceptions.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Program.DoIt().Wait();
    }

    private static async Task DoIt()
    {
        System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
        var task1 = wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://www.google.com.au");
        Console.WriteLine(await task1);
        Console.WriteLine("done!"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But adding a simple Console.ReadLine() in main did the trick. The problem was that Main would exit before the async method would have had a chance to run.

Comment: `Console.ReadLine()` did the trick because it blocked main thread so the thread pool thread which is executing network operation had enough time to complete.